# How do I write join in Ebean Java ORM language

Tags: java, mysql, sql, orm, ebean

Currently my code is

```
    int customerId = 4;
    String sql = "select id from coupon as A join coupon_use "
            + "as B on A.id=B.coupon where B.customer=" + customerId 
            + " and B.like_at is not null;";


   RawSql rawSql = RawSqlBuilder.parse(sql).create();  
   Query<Coupon> query = Ebean.find(Coupon.class);  
   query.setRawSql(rawSql);  
   List<Coupon> list = query.findList(); 
   return ok(Json.toJson(list));
```

How do I avoid writing manual sql query but still have the ORM generate that query and return me the result?

Answer (score 0):

Ebean will add appropriate joins based on the paths/properties used in the where and order by etc.

where couponUse.likeAt is not null.

Assuming couponUse.likeAt is the correct expression path ... Ebean will add a join to support the expression automatically.